# F# value restriction for seq<obj> but not list<obj>?

Tags: f#, type-inference, value-restriction

Value restriction error:

```
let myFn (s : string) (args : obj seq) = ()
let myOtherFn = myFn ""
```

No value restriction error:

```
let myFn (s : string) (args : obj list) = ()
let myOtherFn = myFn ""
```

Why?

Answer (score 4):

All bindings are a subject for [automatic generalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx).

Since `seq<'T>` is an interface (an alias for IEnumrable) , the inferred type for `myOtherFn` would be
`val myOtherFn : ('_a -> unit) when '_a :> seq<obj>`
which is generic, yet, myOtherFn is not a function declaration (read **Value Restriction** part in the link above), so automatic generalization cannot deduce that this is the same as `val myOtherFn : seq<obj> -> unit`.

To force automatic generalization you can add explicit parameter to myOtherFn
`let myOtherFn args = myFn "" args`

Comment: This is the cause, but the relevant difference isn't that seq is an interface, but rather that list is sealed. Use for example `obj ResizeArray` in place of the list, and it will give the value restriction error as well.